# To prove an identity about vector Subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ be vector subspaces of $W$, then if
$S_i =\dim V_i $,  $ S_{ij} =\dim (Vi \cap  Vj)$, $S_{ijk} = \dim (V1 \cap V2 \cap V3)$
Prove or disprove:
$\dim (V_1 + V_2 + V_3) = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 - S_{12} - S_{13} - S_{23} + S_{123}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $V_1$, $V_2$, and $V_3$ be three lines in $\mathbb R^2$ intersecting in the origin.

$S_1 = S_2 = S_3 = 1$, and the rest ($S_{12}$, $S_{123}$, etc.) are $0$.